# Not able to authenticate DLP API

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp

I have followed the google documentation to authenticate but in spite of doing everything i'm still getting the same error.

`DLP API has not been used in project ****** before or it 
is disabled. Enable it by visiting 
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/dlp.googleapis.com/overview?project=******** then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.`

I have followed all instructions here :
https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/quickstart-json
But still i'm not able to resolve it.

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated .

Comment: You should be careful not to provide your project-id

Comment: Also, make sure you have enabled the DLP API. Go to Dev Console > APIs & Services, click on Enable APIs and Services and enable DLP API

Comment: @LundinCast: That's not my project_id.My project_id is different but not suer why i'm getting this project-id in error.i have enabled the API from console but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the usable-auth-library is a global Google-owned project where quota is pooled from when using application default credentials for authentication.

You can get round this by [authenticating gcloud with a service account](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/authorizing#authorizing_with_a_service_account) from your own project. The command `gcloud auth print-access-token` will return an authorization token that you should be able to use successfully.